# Contraposition over Universal and Existential Quantifiers

Tags: first-order-logic

Given the following argument:

(i) $(\forall_x)(S(x)\rightarrow N(x))$,

(ii) $(\forall_x)(V(x)\rightarrow\lnot N(x))$,

(C) $(\forall_x)(V(x)\rightarrow\lnot S(x))$

The proof is given as Assume $V(x)$. By (ii), $\lnot N(x)$. By (i), $\lnot S(x)$. Thus, $\lnot S(x)$ follows from $V(x)$, and the conclusion holds.

However, given the following argument:

(i) $(\exists_x)(G(x)\rightarrow C(x))$,

(ii) $(\exists_x)(S(x)\rightarrow\lnot N(x))$,

(C) $(\exists_x)(S(x)\rightarrow\lnot G(x))$

The same proof would not work. From what I gather, it is the rule of the contrapositive in the first proof that allows it to work? If this is the case, is there a law somewhere that states the same cannot apply to wffs over an existential quantifier?

Comment: It's rather about the meaning of the quantifiers. In the first case, if we pick an arbitrary $x$, the formulas in both (i) and (ii) must hold. However, in the second case it's not guaranteed that there's an element which simultaneously satisfy both conditions.

Comment: First of all, the first argument "works" because there is a common predicate in the premises, and this we can exploit the transitivity of $\to$. In addition, the rules (and the semantics) for the two quantifiers are not the same.